# SQL query in java with single quote

Tags: java, sql

I have a query that I want run in java:

```
SELECT md5(CONCAT(md5('{clear password}') , '{salt}'));
```

Its for my application to connect and use the same username/password as my forum.

Its work but when `salt` contain the character `'` it give an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

How would I write this query in java to cater for the ' if its there and not if its not there?

regards.

Comment: Show us the code that you use to set the parameters.  If you're doing string concatenation, you will need to escape the strings properly.  Also this is a REALLY bad idea due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  You should use prepared statements instead.  That will fix both issues.

Comment: @Chris Thompson hi. resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select md5(CONCAT(md5(\"" + password + "\") , \"" + pwdSalt + "\""); is what I used, How would i write the query for prepaired statement? can you give example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow your question, then you could do it with something like this -

```
String sql = "select md5(CONCAT(md5(?), ?))";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1, password);
  ps.setString(2, pwdSalt);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another possible solution is to perform the hash and salt in Java -

```
// A password hashing method.
public static String hashPassword(String in, String salt) {
  try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); // <-- Or, SHA-256
    md.update(salt.getBytes());        // <-- Prepend salt.
    md.update(in.getBytes());
    // md.update(salt.getBytes());     // <-- Or, append salt.

    byte[] out = md.digest();
    return bytesToHex(out);            // <-- Return the Hex Hash.
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "";
}

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] byteArr) {  
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
  Formatter fmt = new Formatter(sb);  
  for (byte b : byteArr) {  
    fmt.format("%02x", b);  
  }  
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, I wouldn't use MD5 in 2014. SHA-256 would be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

Example of prepared queries:

```
/*
 * Some code
 */
String strSQL = "select md5(concat(md5(?),?))"
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL)) {
    ps.setString(1, password);
    ps.setString(2, pwdSalt);
    try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        rs.first();
        // Do whatever you need to do
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // ...
    }
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // ...
}

/*
 * More code
 */
```