# SQLiteException: near "t": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I'm receiving the following error from my insert db call.

"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "t": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO OCR(bmp, title, description) VALUES ('[B@9430d52', 'Result:', '
pacifism 
Enchant creature 
Creature can't attack Or 
That 
—Knrtce of Qal Sima

');

This is my insert statement

```
String INSERT_TO_DB = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " ("+
            COLUMN_BITMAP + ", " +
            COLUMN_TITLE + ", " +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION +") " +
            "VALUES ('" + getBytes(ocr.getBitmap()) + "', '" + ocr.getTitle() + "', '" + ocr.getDescription() + "');";

    db.execSQL(INSERT_TO_DB);
```

The thing is it was working on other images, i'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that there's a lot of "/n" in the description it's trying to insert into the db.

Comment: You have a single quote in your `getDescription()`, which is one reason why you should use prepared statements rather than string concatentation for SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query in java with single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265396/sql-query-in-java-with-single-quote)

Comment: ah i see where the issue is. Android studio is pretty brand new to me, i'll have a look into Prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Never put string values directly into an SQL statement; use parameters instead.

It is not necessary to use a prepared statement object to achieve this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT ... VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
           new Object[]{ ocr.getTitle(), ... });
```

And there is a helper function that constructs the statement for you, and handles binary data correctly:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, ocr.getTitle());
cv.put(COLUMN_BITMAP, ocr.getBitmap()); // byte array
...
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```